# PHP if statement isn't working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress index page that only shows posts if they have a featured image. This is my content.php code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    echo '<div class="small-index-thumbnail clear">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '" rel="bookmark">';
    echo the_post_thumbnail('index-thumb');
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
    </div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

I'm just wondering if this is enough code for someone to tell me why it's still showing the posts, despite the posts not having a featured image. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the out put of "has_post_thumbnail()" function? ex: die(has_post_thumbnail());

Comment: `var_dump(has_post_thumbnail());` would be th ebest way to see what is returned

Comment: how are you getting these post, did you set `'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'` in your query

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it looks right but there is a **note** about this on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail), which is something like this:

```
// Must be inside a loop.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    // ...
}
```

**Note The above code apparently fails in some instances and the below code is "recommended"**

```
if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) {
    // some code
} else {
    // some code
}
```

Check [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) if needed.